# Better compression for WAR/EAR files?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar, compression

Is there a way to better compress WAR files (which is basically a ZIP file containing a lot of other ZIP files, that contain java *.class files)?

ZIP does not exploit inter-file similarities (and is quite old anyway).

Some archivers uncompress files that are compressed with inferior method before archiving them (and restore the old state when unarchiving).

This would be of course for archiving purposes, as application servers expect actual WAR/EAR files.

Comment: Use 7-zip's functionality for a little extra compression. The algorithm is more efficient at compressing than most zip utilities and has the advantage of still being standard and readable.

Comment: @Necreaux it doesn't help much. Example: original WAR is 29.8 MB. putting it into 7z gives 30.2 MB. Extracting the WAR (gives 33.6 MB) and compressing the files with 7z: 29.1 MB. Extracting (and deleting) each contained JAR (in /WEB-INF/lib) gives 71.2 MB which compresses with 7z to 13.8 MB. So compressing already zipped data doesn't do much. Recompressing on the other hand halves the size (compared to original WAR)!

Comment: Yes, you would have to recursively extract and recompress all archives inside the WAR file, this would include JARs, zip files, etc. As you say, compressing already compressed data doesn't do anything.